# Migrate Python3 environment to virtual - managing import dependencies

Tags: dependencies, virtualenv, local, freeze, python-3.8

I'm running Python3.8.5 on Ubuntu 20.04. I've been putting off working from virtual envs for my projects so I have some third party packages in my local environment. I've been using this OS for about 1 month so not too many third party packages.

I aim to clean up my Python environment and use this as clean slate for future virtual envs.

Am I right in assuming the best way is to remove all third party packages I've installed via pip? If so how do I know which ones to remove? I've read a few nightmare stories so don't want to go willy nilly deleting packages without knowing what they are or if they are built-ins.

Here is the list of outputs from `python3 -m pip freeze` command.
Note
`>> python3 --version` = `Python 3.8.5` which is my default:

```
appdirs==1.4.4
apturl==0.5.2
asn1crypto==1.4.0
backcall==0.2.0
bcrypt==3.1.7
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
black==20.8b1
blinker==1.4
Brlapi==0.7.0
bs4==0.0.1
cached-property==1.5.2
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.14.5
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
coincurve==15.0.0
colorama==0.4.3
command-not-found==0.3
cryptography==2.8
cupshelpers==1.0
cytoolz==0.11.0
dbus-python==1.2.16
decorator==5.0.5
defer==1.0.6
distro==1.4.0
distro-info===0.23ubuntu1
duplicity==0.8.12.0
entrypoints==0.3
eth-hash==0.3.1
eth-typing==2.2.2
eth-utils==1.10.0
ethereum==2.3.2
fasteners==0.14.1
future==0.18.2
html5lib==1.1
httplib2==0.14.0
idna==2.8
ipython==7.22.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
jedi==0.18.0
joblib==1.0.1
key==0.4
keyring==18.0.1
language-selector==0.1
launchpadlib==1.10.13
lazr.restfulclient==0.14.2
lazr.uri==1.0.3
lockfile==0.12.2
louis==3.12.0
lxml==4.6.3
macaroonbakery==1.3.1
Mako==1.1.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
monotonic==1.5
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
netifaces==0.10.4
numpy==1.20.2
oauthlib==3.1.0
olefile==0.46
pandas==1.2.3
paramiko==2.6.0
parso==0.8.2
pathspec==0.8.1
pbkdf2==1.3
pexpect==4.6.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==7.0.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.18
protobuf==3.6.1
py-ecc==5.2.0
pycairo==1.16.2
pycparser==2.20
pycryptodome==3.10.1
pycups==1.9.73
pyethash==0.1.27
Pygments==2.8.1
PyGObject==3.36.0
PyJWT==1.7.1
pymacaroons==0.13.0
PyNaCl==1.3.0
PyPDF2==1.26.0
pyRFC3339==1.1
pysha3==1.0.2
python-apt==2.0.0+ubuntu0.20.4.4
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-debian===0.1.36ubuntu1
pytz==2019.3
pyxdg==0.26
PyYAML==5.3.1
regex==2020.11.13
reportlab==3.5.34
repoze.lru==0.7
requests==2.22.0
requests-unixsocket==0.2.0
rlp==1.2.0
scrypt==0.8.17
SecretStorage==2.3.1
selenium==3.141.0
simplejson==3.16.0
six==1.14.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
speedtest-cli==2.1.2
systemd-python==234
toml==0.10.2
toolz==0.11.1
traitlets==5.0.5
typed-ast==1.4.2
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
ubuntu-advantage-tools==20.3
ubuntu-drivers-common==0.0.0
ufw==0.36
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.25.8
usb-creator==0.3.7
wadllib==1.3.3
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
xkit==0.0.0
```

I had a look at the [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/#) and checked both `python3 -m pip freeze` `--user` & `--local` options but saw lots of packages which I didn't directly install. The outputs of these were less than above example.

Comment: Normally in a virtual environment the other libraries installed as `--user` or `--local` are not "seen". So there is no real need to clean that up. You can start using virtual environments straight away and each virtual environment is going to be "clean".

Answer (score 1):

Turns out its never too late to start using virtual environments. Following on from @sinoroc above, each venv establishes a 'clean' python version which only includes built-in methods and drops all third-party packages (for Ubuntu 20.04 `--version` = 3.8.5). See below for pip freeze after initializing virtual environment venv:

```
>>> python3 -m venv venv
>>> ls
Desktop    Downloads      Pictures  repos  Templates  Videos
Documents  Public         snap      venv
>>> source ./venv/bin/activate
(venv) izpad ~ 
>>> python3 -m pip install -U pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.0.2
    Uninstalling pip-20.0.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.0.2
Successfully installed pip-21.0.1
(venv) izpad ~ 
>>> pip freeze
pkg-resources==0.0.0
>>> python --version
Python 3.8.5
```